# how to GET json data from localhost in flutter application?

Tags: android, postgresql, flutter, django-rest-framework, android-emulator

I am trying to fetch `Json` data from `API` on my local host( i Used `PostgreSQL` and `Django` ) and i run my server it works fine and my localhost link for my Json data is 
  but i cant access the localhost it gives my connection refused error i want to know is there any particular steps to connect to the localhost with flutter and if there is any configuration i need to setup to my android emulator to connect to the localhost
My Json data

Comment: Every Android device is it's own localhost. Every PC is it's own localhost. Every emulator is it's own localhost. Where are you talking about?

Comment: i am talking about my own pc is running a django server which contains restful api , i want my emulator to connect this localhost and use the api

Comment: And... how are you trying to connect? Should we guess?

Comment: actually your question is my problem i cant connect my localhost easily as i can connect any normal like 
  'https://api.punkapi.com

Comment: iam trying to connect my emulator to the Django server which is running locally too -django is my backend language- to fetch data from the rest api

Comment: `which is running locally ` ??? Locally on your emulator??? Yes i knew that already. You told that before. Dont just repeat yourself. Now tell: How exactly are you trying to connect? Which url for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I changed my IP to `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.